# Wrapper Class member access

Tags: c, struct, queue, wrapper, member

So I have a generic doubly-linked queue struct with sentinel nodes:

```
// Queue node:
struct _QNode {
    struct _QNode *prev;     /* Previous list element. */
    struct _QNode *next;     /* Next list element.    */
};
typedef struct _QNode QNode;

// Queue object:
struct _Queue {
    QNode front;    // sentinel node at the front of the queue
    QNode rear;     // sentinel node at the tail of the queue
};
```

And a "duct-tape" struct that serves to load integer values into the queue nodes

```
struct _Tape {
    int32_t payload;    // user data field
    QNode node;       // generic node
};
```

And a wrapper class IntegerQueue that combines the two.

My question is how would you access the payload variable of a given node that you are trying to pop?

Comment: Unrelated: It's a bad idea to prefix identifiers with `_` followed by a capital letter. Such identifiers are specified as reserved by the standard ("All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.") It's better to use a `_t` suffix instead.

Comment: @NikosC. The `_t` suffix is reserved by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02); see _§2.2.2 The Name Space_ and the last line of the first table (which is split across two pages).  It's better than the `_[A-Z]` names, but not 100% reliable.

Answer (score 1):

With what you have you can build nice lists of QNodes. But if you have a Queue of such QNodes, you can only access the QNodes in it, not your Tape, at least not in a accepted way (You could argue, that each QNode is contained in a Tape-struct, and therefore subtract some value from the QNode's address to get the Tape-address, but that gets you shot if somebody else sees it).
So I think you have somehow to put your payload into the QNodes. If you would use C++, then you could use Templates to do that in a generic way, here you could use macros, or inside Queue a void-pointer and then cast it to your payload-type (which again gets you shot).

Comment: A way with less probability to get shot would be to have QNode as first field of Tape, then if `node` is of type `QNode*`, you could write `((Tape*)node)->payload` which I assume would work on most systems.

Answer (score 0):

An orthodox way of handling things would be:

```
typedef struct QNode QNode;
struct QNode
{
    QNode *prev;     /* Previous list element. */
    QNode *next;     /* Next list element.     */
    void  *data;     /* Data for this node     */
};
```

This can be used to store pointers to any data type (structure or simple type).  You can then create a type-safe wrapper around a queue for such a generic type.  Note that this is non-invasive; it does not alter the type being queued, which is often beneficial.  One caveat: if you're planning to store `int32_t`, then the pointer will use at least as much space as the data (8 bytes for the pointer on a 64-bit machine, vs 4 bytes for the data).  It would be more economical to use a specialized type (`QNodeInt32`) to store the values directly.  Genericism often costs space.